# После создания контейнера в докере он не запускается, подскажите где я ошибка в dockerfile?

Tags: nginx, docker, dockerfile

dockerfile

```
# get image from...
FROM debian:9

# maintainer
LABEL maintainer="mail@mail.ru"

# updates
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

# install some utilites 
RUN apt-get install -y wget build-essential libpcre3 libpcre3-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev 

# modules
RUN cd /usr/local/src && wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.19.8.tar.gz
RUN cd /usr/local/src && tar -zxvf nginx-1.19.8.tar.gz
RUN cd /usr/local/src/nginx-1.19.8 $$ ./configure --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-pcr
RUN cd /usr/local/src/nginx-1.19.8 $$ make
RUN cd /usr/local/src/nginx-1.19.8 $$ make install

RUN echo \
[Unit]\
Description=The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server \
After=syslog.target network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target \
Wants=network-online.target \
[Service] \
Type=forking \
PIDFile=/var/run/nginx.pid \
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t \
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx \
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -s reload \
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID \
PrivateTmp=true \
[Install] \
WantedBy=multi-user.target \ >  /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service

EXPOSE 80 22 443

CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

Comment: 1. Ошибка `docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "nginx": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`. Соответственно nginx не установлен. В файле ошибка `$$ ./configure` - почему доллары? Должно быть `&&` 2. Зачем собирать Nginx, если уже есть готовый образ https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx 3. Зачем systemd ? Концепция докера - отказ от всех инит-систем и запуск программы напрямую, что собственно и сделано в конце вашего файла.

Comment: Спасибо большое, после исправления ошибок все заработало